# Get max Date and change datatype (Sqlite with Python)

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using python to get max Date from a database. Manage to get the max date using code below and I would like to convert the result's datatype and use it later on. But the problem now is I am using index to get the result and not able to convert into other datatype and the errors is "**'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**" what is the correct method to solve it?

```
    maxDate= 'SELECT max(date) FROM BHDataBase'
    test2 = cur.execute(maxDate)
    print(test2.fetchone()[0]) #-ok
    print(type(test2.fetchone()[0])) #using index to get result
    #(test2.fetchone()[0]).astype(str) #not able to convert the result's datatype
```

Answer (score 0):

The query returns one row. After the first `fetchone()`, there are no more rows to retrieve. Subsequent `fetchone()` returns None.